# /etc/netplan: No such file or directory

Tags: networking, 18.04, netplan

Upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 today and want to start using netplan, but it doesn't appear to be installed? I tried to install it with `apt install netplan` but none of the files/directories listed on the [Migrating to Netplan](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MigratingToNetplan) page exist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Netplan is shipped in the `netplan.io` package.  Running `apt install netplan.io` will give you the /etc/netplan directory; you will need to provide your own config files in this directory, with a .yaml extension.

If the `netplan.io` package was not installed for you on upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04, then it appears you are missing the `ubuntu-minimal` package.  It is recommended that you install this package to ensure you have the standard Ubuntu experience.

Comment: I migrated to 18.0.4 and I do have the /etc/netplan directory but when I ran sudo netplan generate nothing happened. Command does exist. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053757/netplan-generate-generates-nothing